# Writing to a File in Java using FileWriter

Tags: java

I would like to write to a file after a set of characters. For example, if I want to write `xyz` into a file `test.txt` which contains string `hello world`. I want write after the letter `w`. The output should be `hello wxyzorld` in the file.

How do it do it? Using a `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter` I can write to a file but not at a certain position. Could you help me if there is anyway I can do it?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913543/java-writing-to-a-file-with-specific-offset

Comment: HI Aravind! Can you show us the code that you have tried to write so far? From there we can guide you to a solution. You will have better success getting answers to your questions when you show your existing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/test.txt")));
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int offset = 7;

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
                    if(i == offset) {
                        stringBuilder.append("xyz" + line.charAt(i));
                    } else if(i == line.length()-1) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line.charAt(i) +"\n");
                    } else {
                        stringBuilder.append(line.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
        }

        System.out.println(stringBuilder);
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Something like this perhaps? You can append the rest of the lines accordingly to your StringBuilder.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have use the method that you gave and the code works for me. Thanks

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer if it worked for you :)